# C# HashSet<string> to single string

Tags: c#

I have a `HashSet<string>` that is added to periodically.  What I want to do is to cast the entire HashSet to a string without doing a foreach loop.  Does anybody have an example?

Comment: A single string? As in concatenate the values?

Comment: I am curious about something. I have seen *dozens* of SO questions of the form "I want to do something that obviously requires a loop, and I don't want to use a loop". **Why?** Whence this hatred people have for loops?

Comment: I think people want to improve the semantic clarity of their code. If you had `mySet.ItemsAsOneBigString()` instead of `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); foreach(String s in myset) sb.append(s); return sb.ToString();` Yeah, it's small, but then so are many other of the C# syntactic and framework sugar "cubes" ;) that make code clearer to read and determine intent.

Comment: @Eric I saw a lot of people reading some book about Big-O Notation and coming out with the feeling of "I need to avoid loops at all costs because they are slow" and somehow assuming that the Framework has some magic Bulk-Memory-Copy way of avoiding the loop. Not saying that Mike is one of these people, but I've seen them.

Comment: @Michael: The framework is not magical. If you have to do the same thing many times, there's either a loop or a recursion in there *somewhere*.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You will loop over the contents, whether you explicitly write one or not.

However, to do it without the explicit writing, and if by "cast" you mean "concatenate", you would write something like this

```
string output = string.Join("", yourSet); // .NET 4.0
string output = string.Join("", yourSet.ToArray()); // .NET 3.5
```

Comment: +1, But also worth noting that the .NET 3.5 version is "worse" than an explicit loop: it requires two passes through the data (one for the `ToArray` call and one for the `Join` call) and an extra allocation (the array generated by `ToArray`).

Comment: I like @Brian's answer--it even gives you control over what the loop should put between values: string.Join(", ", set). Would there be performance reasons to prefer the 4.0 syntax above?

Answer (score 14):

If you want a single string that is a concatenation of the values in the HashSet, this should work...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var set = new HashSet<string>();
        set.Add("one");
        set.Add("two");
        set.Add("three");
        var count = string.Join(", ", set);
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a single method to get all the hashset's items concatenated, you can create a extension method.

[]'s

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        HashSet<string> hashset = new HashSet<string>();
        hashset.Add("AAA");
        hashset.Add("BBB");
        hashset.Add("CCC");
        Assert.AreEqual<string>("AAABBBCCC", hashset.AllToString());
    }
}

public static class HashSetExtensions
{
    public static string AllToString(this HashSet<string> hashset)
    {           
        lock (hashset) 
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in hashset)
                sb.Append(item);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq:

```
hashSet.Aggregate((a,b)=>a+" "+b)
```

which inserts a white space between two elements of your hashset